# The Rolling Dead, Sphero AR Android SDK?

Tags: sphero-api

I was hoping that the Android version of the AR SDK was released since "The Rolling Dead" was released on Android.

Is it around for download now? What was used to create "The Rolling Dead"?

~Danilo

Comment: Really? Of the 12 views, -5 comments? Are any of you actual Sphero API programmers? Please. Is there a credible Sphero rep that knows if the Android AR Sphero API is released?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Sphero AR SDK only supports iOS, but we are working on Android.

https://github.com/orbotix/Sphero-AR-SDK

Comment: We just need to cleanup a few things in it for public release, keep an eye out for it in the next few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK was added and then removed because it was unstable, the team no longer has time to update it.

Small discussion at the sphero forum:
http://community.gosphero.com/discussion/59/sphero-ar-sdk-for-android#latest

I'm interested in testing with Sphero AR for android as well and occasionally check in every few months or so to see if there's any new plans, thought I'd leave an updated answer :)